# sqlite primary key create table error

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

# set database variables
sqlite_db_filename = '/samba/anonymous/vacuum_control.sqlite'
table_name = 'user_recipe'
new_field_1 = 'recipe_id'
field_type_1 = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'
new_field_2 = 'recipe_name'
field_type_2 = 'TEXT'
new_field_3 = 'use_vacuum'
field_type_3 = 'INTEGER'


# Connecting to the database file
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_db_filename)
c = conn.cursor()

# Creating a new SQLite table with x columns

c.execute('CREATE TABLE {tn} ({nf1} {ft1} {nf2} {ft2})'\
    .format(tn=table_name, nf1=new_field_1, ft1=field_type_1, nf2=new_field_2, ft2=field_type_2))

# Committing changes and closing the connection to the database file
conn.commit()
```

## QUESTION

The current code produces the error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_base_config.py", line 20, in <module>
    .format(tn=table_name, nf1=new_field_1, ft1=field_type_1, nf2=new_field_2, ft2=field_type_2))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "recipe_name": syntax error"
```

If I change `field_type_1` to just `"INTEGER"` it works fine. I've looked at many other examples and it seems valid to include `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

SQLite version 3.8.7.1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the comma after {ft1}:

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE {tn} ({nf1} {ft1}, {nf2} {ft2})'\
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you just want to set on of the column as primary key, then I suggest using this syntax.

```
    # Creating a second table with 1 column and set it as PRIMARY KEY
    # note that PRIMARY KEY column must consist of unique values!
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE {tn} ({nf} {ft} PRIMARY KEY)'\
            .format(tn=table_name2, nf=new_field, ft=field_type))
```

You can see this example [here](https://github.com/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/sqlite3_howto/code/create_new_db.py)